# Surface area of a curve revolved around the polar axis

Tags: calculus

"Find the area of the surface obtained by revolving the curve $r=\cos \theta$, $ 0 < \theta < \pi $ about the polar axis. What is the arc length of this curve?"

I know how to find the arc length, but I'm not sure what it means to revolve around the polar axis.

Comment: Take a look at the diagram at the top right on this Wikipedia page on the [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 0):

Hint...the curve is a circle of radius $\frac 12$

Comment: The OP stated, "I know how to find the arc length, but I'm not sure what it means to revolve around the polar axis. "